Redirect http to https app engine flexible nodejs runtime
I have a Next.js client application with a Google managed custom domain from goDaddy. I want to redirect my HTTP traffic from http‍://app.test.com to https‍://app.test.com. When I explicitly hit it with HTTP, it does not redirect to HTTPS. The back-end is in dot net core handled separately.
App engine flex has no effect of below both these in app.yaml
secure: always
redirect_http_response_code: 301

How can I redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS?
goDaddy DNS forward section have the redirection for root domain to my subdomain, which is my current need and there is no other option to add redirection for HTTP subdomain to HTTPS subdomain?

Where are you performing SSL termination? Cause it looks to me like you have 3 options with appengine (external load balancer, default appengine load balancer or your application container). The answer will probably depend on that.

I am using the app engine with flex env with no docker so no containers, guessing the default app engine load balancer bcz i did not created or linked any external load balancer present in gcp..

HTTP/HTTPS are not a subdomain, so that's why you don't find anything about it in your DNS settings.

The setting secure isn't listed as an option for app.yaml for flex env (see docs). It's listed for standard env (see doc)
To solve your problem, the Google documentation says

To instruct the browser to prefer https over http for a given page or entire domain, set the Strict-Transport-Security header in your responses. e.g Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

Strict-Transport Security

The HTTP Strict-Transport-Security response header (often abbreviated as HSTS) informs browsers that the site should only be accessed using HTTPS, and that any future attempts to access it using HTTP should automatically be converted to HTTPS.


could you provide any example how can i use the Strict Transport in nextjs app you mean by middleware?

Don't understand the meaning of by middleware

could you give me some sample code of your solution?

See if this documentation helps
